# Keyboard shortcut for switching input sources by Super + Space turns on scroll lock

Tags: shortcut-keys

Input Sources on my computer are English(US) and Thai and I use default Input Source Switching, Super+Space, but Super+Space turns on scroll lock.
In order to turn off scroll lock, I have to switch the Input Source to English(US).

[image: Settings]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem happened either after upgrading from Ubuntu 20.04 to 21.10 or after upgrading from 21.10 to 22.04. So, I decided to do clean install of 22.04 LTS, there is no problem like this.